# How do I get Python to extract weekdays from dates?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, weekday

I'm quite new in the Python world and I need to extract the exact weekdays from a long column of specific dates in my dataset.
The column looks like this:

```
0       1/5/2019
1       3/8/2019
2       3/3/2019
3      1/27/2019
4       2/8/2019
         ...    
995    1/29/2019
996     3/2/2019
997     2/9/2019
998    2/22/2019
999    2/18/2019
Name: Date, Length: 1000, dtype: object
```

I've been trying with  the packages datetime and calendar as well as coding with for loop, but I can't figure out how to get Python to read the entire column and let me extract the weekdays in a new column.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your data is in a pandas Series, which has date functionality built in.

First you have to convert the string values to date objects, and then you can use the date functionality through `.dt` to get the weekday:

```
import pandas as pd
timeseries = pd.Series(["1/27/2015", "5/4/2012"])
pd.to_datetime(timeseries).dt.weekday  # --> [1, 4]
pd.to_datetime(timeseries).dt.day_name()  # --> ["Tuesday", "Friday"]
```

Pitfall: the default for `pd.to_datetime` is month/day/year. If your data is in day/month/year format and you don't specify the format, pandas will parse whatever rows it can as m/d/y and the remaining rows as d/m/y, silently messing up *some* of the dates.